# Doctrine DQL, using the IN statement with entities

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, dql

Is it in Doctrine possible to use the IN statement and pass a list of entities as parameter for the IN statement?

For example, with with the following relation:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Calendar", mappedBy="education", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $calendar;
```

I would like to do a query like:

```
 SELECT p FROM Education p WHERE p.calendar IN (:calendar)
```

An as :calendar parameter an array of entities.

```
$query->setParameter('calendar', array($singleEntity,$singleEntity2));
```

But that gives the following error:

```
near 'calendar IN (:calendar)': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField
```

Comment: For DQL (not DML?) you will need to join the calendar:  SELECT education FROM EducationClassName education LEFT JOIN education.calendar calendar WHERE calendar.id IN (:calendarIds) I have always used ids for IN statements so I know they work but you can try using the full entity without the .id and see what happens.

Comment: @Cerad Updated DML to DQL.

Comment: @Cerad That is exactly the workaround that I used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use full entities for the IN statement and DQL will be like

```
$query->select('p')
  ->from('Education', 'p')
  ->where($query->expr()->in('p.calendar', ':values'))
  ->setParameter('values',  array($singleEntity,$singleEntity2));
```

I have used this before quite a few times if I recall correctly and it always worked. I usually use the JOIN and an attribute like Cerad suggested but this should work too.